# BARBA.js transition gets broken after adding woocommerce links to menu

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, transition, barbajs

Today I bump on a weird issue, that seems to happen with WooCommerce plugin (well im stuck on it for 4 days T_T)

**THE PROBLEM:**

Barba Transition animation gets broken at `afteafterLeave( )` hook after i add "WooCommerce" links (pages) onto the main menu.

**DETAILS:**

Im developing localy at my machine using MAMP.
it all works fine while coding the menu interactions and while i add only 2 pages from my user's pages it works fine..
but after i add woocommerce pages
the navigation dosnt work as intended.. it gets broken while going thru the hooks/transition timeline

while transitioning between hooks `before( ) > beforeLeave( ) > leave( ) > afterLeave( )` <- IT GETS BROKEN HERE AND RESTART THE TRANSITION
and gets stuck in the same page. (without addint data.next.container)

it dosn't go thru `beforeEnter( ) > enter( ) > afterEnter( ) > after( )`

I don't quite understand the issue here.
what may be the couse?

it seems like after adding the woocomerce pages into the menu, the wordpress instalation starts ignoring the data-barba="wrapper" and the data-barba="container" and is unabble to iterate ove data object

On wordpress im using this layout:

```
<body data-barba="wrapper" > 
   <header id="masthead"> </header> 
   <div id="barba-container" data-barba="container" > 
      <div id="page" class="site" > </div> 
   </div> 
</body>
```

im using barba-container like that (on a div above all content) so i dont have to add it separatly on every wordpress single pages `index.php, Single.php, page.php`